# Mesmo após adicionar o arquivo no gitignore, ele continua no github

Tags: git, github

Minha situação é o seguinte: eu criei um projeto, subi no github e depois de muito tempo, percebi que subi a pasta `node_modules`, e não desejo ela por lá. Criei o `.gitignore` e add a pasta lá, mas mesmo assim, continua trackeando. Já fiz o clássico:

```
git pull origin master
git rm -r folderName
git commit -m "rm folderName"
git push origin master
```

e não funcionou. Também tentei o:

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
git commit -m "rm ignored files"
```

mas também sem sucesso. Só não apago arquivo por arquivo dentro do github porque ficaria inviável, e não gostaria de recomeçar um novo repositório porque os commits são para registro de uma entrevista de emprego.

Answer (score 3):

Como o diretório node_modules já está sendo rastreado como parte do repositório, a regra `.gitignore` não se aplicará a ele.

Você precisa desimpedir o diretório do git usando

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -m "removing node_modules"
```

Você pode executar os 2 acima em git-bash.

Depois disso, a regra .gitignore ignorará o diretório.

Observe que isso removerá o diretório node_modules de seus outros repositórios assim que você inserir as alterações. Somente o repositório original onde você fez esse commit ainda terá a pasta node_modules.

Não esqueça que no .gitignore deve estar definido **node_modules/** para este ser ignorado.

Esses comandos devem ser efectuados por um [git client](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

https://www.it-swarm.dev/pt/git/.gitignore-nao-esta-ignorando-diretorios/1046576469/

Comment: Funcionou aqui, muito obrigado!
O que eu precisei fazer a mais era trocar para a branch master antes, esqueci de mencionar esse detalhe :)